Why is WordPress adding in a subcategory to my url when it has no parent page?
I have created a web page in my WordPress website. It has no parent page. It is a web page detailing my web design services and is named accordingly eg. small-business-website-design.
I just want it to be a standalone page, but for some reason WordPress is adding in a parent category in the url slug, so instead of:
https://www.stevesims.com/small-business-website-design/
the page loads from https://www.stevesims.com/wordpress-website-design-services-uk/small-business-website-design/
I have set the page to be my front page, but I think that is irrelevant and not causing the issue above. I have checked and have no redirects etc. in place and wouldn't expect this to be the cause as it is a new page.
I would welcome any thoughts with a view to providing a solution for the issue.

